# Database get duration from two timestamp rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time

I have a table with a log of ticket usages. How can I group two consecutive row to get time duration?
 Eg: For the first 4 rows I should get

```
ticket_id  duration
15874      03:03:31
15874      01:10:35
```

Data example
[image]

Table structure
[image]

Comment: Tell me how you want duration of ticket as above ??

Comment: If mysql can group two consecutive rows, it would be duration=row2.created_at-row1.created_at

Comment: Updated the post. I hope, this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a sample and the result will be shown with the `GROUP BY` using date from `datetime` and UserID:

```
SELECT start_log.UserID, TIME(start_log.created_id), TIME(end_log.created_id), 
DATE(start_log.created_id), TIMESTAMPDIFF(
MINUTE , start_log.created_id, end_log.created_id ) AS TimeInMin
FROM sample AS start_log
INNER JOIN sample AS end_log ON (start_log.UserID = end_log.UserID
AND start_log.created_id < end_log.created_id )
GROUP BY TIME(start_log.created_id), UserID
```

The output I mean the duration is given in minutes: **Updated**

[image: mysql_output]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I got a last hour requirement, they can enter and exit the building multiple times with the same ticket. This query matches only the first pair.

Comment: I was sure this would happen and I did the above according to your sample data. See what happens?

Comment: Almost, so user `1004` get `in at 10` and `out at 12`, later he get `in at 13` and `out at 18`. The time from `12` to `13` should not be counted because he is outside

Comment: I marked your answer because is both useful and answers to the original question. If you can help me with the last requirement it would be great :)

Comment: I guess, this isn't going to be an issue but let me know if I could help again.

Comment: using `HAVING COUNT(*) != 2` seems to do the trick. Is this the correct way?

Comment: It's ok to use. What are you counting actually?